# Creating a terminal application from a shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script. I want to convert the shell script to an application for Ubuntu which can be installed using (`sudo apt-get install)` command and after installing, the application can run from the terminal by typing the name of the application.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, either http://developer.ubuntu.com/ or http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/ (yes, that's a Debian link, I don't believe Ubuntu has its own version, you can skim over a lot of sections about internal Debian stuff).

Comment: Just to make sure, is your intention to package your script just to be able to run it "from the terminal by typing the name"?

Answer (score 1):

Packaging a binary or script is very simple.  In the most trivial case, you need a `.deb` package which contains a copy of your binary in `usr/bin/yourbinary`.  However, there are a number of things you should take care of if you want others to find it usable.

In concrete terms, have a look at the package [dh-make](http://packages.qa.debian.org/d/dh-make.html), which contains all the infrastructure you need to create a well-behaved Debian package.

When you run `dh_make -s -n` in the directory where you develop your script, you get to fill in some details, such as a package description and your name and email address.  The tool will create a `debian/` directory with some template files which you should either modify or remove.  (The ones with `*.ex` names are probably all good to remove.)

(`dh_make` is particular about the directory name; it will print an error message directing you to use `dh_make -s -n -p yourpackage_0.01` to proceed without renaming the directory.)

- The package should have a useful name and a description.  This is in the `debian/control` file.  This is also where you can make it depend on other packages, or even particular versions of other packages.
- There needs to be a modicum of documentation; the files `debian/README` and `debian/changelog` should be updated to contain more than just the boilerplate. If you have notes for the package itself, you might want to put them in `debian/README.Debian`; otherwise, delete this file.  Similar for `debian/README.source`, i.e. notes for somebody downloading the package's sources with `apt-get source yourpackage`.  These files will end up in `/usr/share/doc/yourpackage` when you install `yourpackage`.  If you want to put other files there, add their names to the (now empty) text file `debian/docs`.  Otherwise, you can delete this file, too.
- Review `debian/copyright` and update it if necessary.  This too will end up in `/usr/share/doc/yourpackage`.

There is a wealth of material about Debian packaging and `dh-make` all over the Internet; this answer is obviously very brief and summaric.  For a really proper package, you need to read and understand all of the [Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).

Comment: For a single script, you might also look at `equivs`, which however is more oriented towards creating an empty meta-package which pulls in other packages as dependencies.  It does have a facility for including arbitrary files in the package as well, though.  The instructions are less oriented towards actually packaging something, but once you understand the basics of `dh_make` you might want to use just a single source file for the entire package, which `equivs` does for you (it basically offers a superset of the `debian/control` file for controlling the entire package).

Comment: To publish the package so that `apt-get` finds it, you need to set up a repo, and add the repo's URL to a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; some package managers also provide a GUI for this. If a public repo is acceptable, Launchpad offers to host a PPA for you, but setting up a private repo isn't too hard, either; you basically need to run `dpkg-scanpackages` to generate the `Packages` file.